# Wrong Activity gets called

Tags: android

I have two Apps with the same Activity called `SettingsActivity`.
In App A I do a 
`startActivity(this, (fullpackagename).SettingsActivity);`

and in the Manifest i got `<activity android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"></activity>`
for registering the Activity.

But at runtime the SettingsActivity of App B is called.

I did project clean already and checking the import dependencies, but without success.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the whole package name to the activity in the manifest file like

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.activities.SettingsActivity"/>
```

assuming you application package name is

```
com.myapp
```